# Removing the extension from a filename

Tags: java, performance, file

Let me know if the given code can be improved or optimized:

```
public static String getFileNameWithoutExtensiotn(File file) {
    String fileName = null;
    if (file.getName().startsWith(".")) {//if starts with "." like .htaccess
        fileName = file.getName();
    } else {
        try {
            fileName = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().lastIndexOf("."));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fileName = file.getName();
        }
    }

    return fileName;
}
```

Comment: First improvement: remove spelling mistake in method name.
Second thought: What about .htaccess.txt ?

Comment: @Teetrinker Do not answer questions in the comments section. Improvements are meant for their own answers.

Comment: @SirPython Sorry, it did not feel thorough enough for an answer.

Comment: @Teetrinker Read [this](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2106/59481) and [this](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1479/59481). In conclusion, short answers are perfectly okay as long as you add sufficient context to them.

Answer (score 6):

Your code can be improved in few lines:

```
        String fileName = file.getName();
        if (fileName.indexOf(".") > 0)
            fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf("."));
        return fileName;
```

As far as catching the exception, an advice, always catch the specific exception, not the generic, so you should be catching `IOException` or `IndexOutOfBoundException` instead of `Exception`. Also, it's always a good idea to log exception somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you misspelled your function name - there's no `t` in there.

Your use of `lastIndexOf` is great, but there's no need to combine it with `startsWith` too.

Additionally, you should get familiar with early-return concepts. They help make code more readable. You also get the file's name multiple times, which is a waste of effort. Consider the much simpler version of your function:

```
public static String getFileNameWithoutExtension(File file) {
    String name = file.getName();
    int pos = name.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (pos > 0 && pos < (name.length() - 1)) {
        // there is a '.' and it's not the first, or last character.
        return name.substring(0,  pos);
    }
    return name;
}
```

If you are familiar with regular expressions they can be helpful in cases like this too. A file extension is anything after a `.` that's not a `.` and is not at the string's beginning.

So, this requires a pattern that uses a positive lookbehind, and then a generic match on the extension:

```
private static final Pattern ext = Pattern.compile("(?<=.)\\.[^.]+$");

public static String getFileNameWithoutExtension(File file) {
    return ext.matcher(file.getName()).replaceAll("");
}
```

Just a thought, probably neither more efficient, nor more readable for a non-familiar person, but you do see code like that, and it's helpful to know your alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are catching an exception:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    fileName = file.getName();
}
```

While you did a good job knowing to catch an exception, you are being very general; you are just capturing `Exception` and tells the person who is reading your code absolutely nothing.

Rather than just catching the generic `Exception`, you should be more specific and catch the exception that will be coming out of that line.

I think the exception coming out of this would be from passing `-1` to `String.substring`, which would happen in there was no last index of `"."`.

After [reading the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)), I discovered that the exception that would be raised from this line is the [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

Now, rather than catching the generic `Exception`, you should catch `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

---

A simpler, maybe faster way of getting the string before the `"."` would be to just `split` the String by the `"."`. Then, you'd be left with an array containing the String before the `"."`.

Now, getting the name would be this:

```
fileName = file.getName().split("\\.", 2)[0];
```

*Note: I passed a `2` as a second parameter to `split` because this limits how many times the string will be split up. By passing a `2`, this limits to the string only being split a single time, which might speed up performance.*

*Note two: since `split` is looking for a regexular expression and `.` is a valid token, I inserted an escape character.*

Comment: thanks @SirPython for the review ... by the way i just decide not show whats is going on in Catch so i did so,,,,,

Comment: If you have `a.b.txt` this will return...

Comment: If you have `a.b.txt`, I think this will return `a`.

Answer (score 2):

You can so this to avoid scanning the string more than once.

```
String fileName = file.getName();
int last = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
return last >= 1 ? fileName.substring(0, last) : fileName;
```

This changes the behaviour slightly in that `.hidden.txt` will return `.hidden`

Comment: The shortest and the cleanest way.